# Python plot values at nodes in meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mesh

I have from

```
    numpy.meshgrid(xx,yy)
```

a rectangular grid.

To get the coordinates (nodes) I split it into two lists X and Y with values:

```
    X = (0.0 , 0.2 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.8 , 1.0)*6
    Y = (0.0 , 0.2 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.8 , 1.0)*6
```

Which gives a grid with 36 points. (think of it as a unit square)

Now i have from solving a linear system of equation another list which have the size (36,1).

I want to plot the values from the (36,1) list at the corresponding nodes in my grid.

So the first 6 points from the (36,1) list lies on the x-axis (Y = 0) and then the following 6 lies on Y = 0.2 and so on.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your output array and:

```
disparray = myarray + (arange(6) * .2)[:,None]
plot(X.flatten(), disparray.flatten(), '.')
```

This should do.

And, of course you can plot with a for loop.

```
figure()
for r in range(myarray.shape[0]):
    plot(X[0], myarray[r] + 0.2*r, 'k')
```

This uses the X values from the first row of your mesh as the X values in the plot and plots each row of your result array `myarray` at offsets 0, 0.2, 0.4... with a black line

Comment: I am having trouble using your first line of code, maybe because I am reading it wrong.

I tried using:

disparray = sol + (arange(6) * .2)[:,None]

But got the following error:

operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (36,1) (6,1)

Comment: @M.Gosvig: What is the problem? if `myarray` has 6 rows, this should work. Just make sure you use the correct namespace, e.g. `np.arange(...)`or `numpy.arange(...)`, as I omitted the prefix (= I'm a lazy pylab user). The same goes with `figure` and `plot`, as they should come from the matplotlib library.

Comment: Okay, so now i have a new array disparray(which was build from X) and my array X.. I don't see how this helps me plot my sol=(36,1) array with values at the meshgrid nodes...

Comment: @M.Gosvig The new array is built so that an offset of .2 per row is added to the values for plotting. However, if you try the second recipe, then you'll see if it draws what you want to see. (The first one should draw the same but with dots.)